# General mean value theorem for integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Studying changing variables under multiple integrals i have encountered such statement:

Using mean value theorem for integral we get:

$ \int\limits_{T(B_j)} f(y) dy= f(y_j)v(T(B_j) $ for some $y_j=T(x_j)\in T(B_j) $

What does mean $v$ in $v(T(B_j))$?

Comment: It (most likely) means the volume/measure of the set $T(B_j)$.

Comment: if $ B_j $ is part of $ \mathbb{R}^n $ it is better to use measure than volume, isn't it?

Comment: To me, this is just a matter of vocabulary... so it doesn't really matter what it's called as long as the concept is clear, but sure, this statement is most likely intended with the Lebesgue measure in mind (you also probably need some assumptions on the region of integration and the function $f$... for example, $f$ being continuous and the region $S$ of integration being compact and connected works; I haven't thought of more general situations).

Comment: Yes, I have this all, but just didnt find it necessary for the question. Thanks for help!